# Server 2012 Storage Spaces HA Cluster with additional JBOD SATA DAS?

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage-spaces

I am looking at building a Windows Server 2012 R2 Storage Spaces High Availability setup, and I had a question.

Can I add a additional enclosure to just one of the servers to host a non-HA array. This enclosure would be used purely to backup a storage array at one of our other locations, and it does not need to be HA, so I would use standard SATA disks instead of SAS disks.

Here is a visual of what I was thinking.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I add a additional enclosure to just one of the servers to host a
>   non-HA array

Yes, just don't let SS own it.